# NVME SSD mit PCIe 2.0?

Tags: nvme

I am currently trying to upgrade my PC with an NVME. I use the Sabertooth 990fx R.2 board from ASUS, which only knows PCIe 2.0. Now I have seen some threads and videos on the internet where users did the same with success. They took a NVME SSD M.2 PCIe 3.0 and combined it with a NVME M.2 PCIe adapter card. Could then achieve up to 1600 MB/s. That would be my goal as well. I don't need to boot from it. Now I bought a cheap used NVME SSD (Samsung PM981a) and tried different adapter cards. With these cards I made sure that "PCIe 2.0 compatible" was included, although they were for PCIe 3.0. All cards brought only 200 - 300 MB/s. I tested it under Linux and Windows. Now I wanted to exclude that my NVMe SSD has a defect and bought a new Samsung 970 EVO Plus to test it. But same results. I am at a loss as to what the problem is.

The following questions arise for me:

1. since there are hardly any electronic components on the adapter cards, I wonder if the adapter card is so crucial for this.
2. are the older M.2 NVMes possibly equipped with additional chips to ensure full backwards compatibility with PCIe 2.0?
3. how do I get my nearly 2000MB/s with 4 lanes?

**More Details:**
I use crystaldiskbenchmark in Windows and fio + dd in Linux. CPU Usage was 5 %. PCIe Slot is the last one with a x16 with 8 Lanes.
Cards I used:

1. https://www.amazon.de/dp/B01FU9JS94?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details
2. https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07SQ12MV5?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details
3. https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07FN3YZ8P?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details

**for the 970 Evo plus, it looks like:**
**lspci**
05:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
**nvme list**
Node             SN                   Model                                    Namespace Usage                      Format           FW Rev

---

/dev/nvme0n1     S4EWNZ0W312177H      Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB             1         121,33  MB /   1,00  TB    512   B +  0 B   2B2QEXM7

Thanks for your info!

Greetings

Comment: How exactly were you testing the speed? What was CPU load during the test; describe the system more, please. In Linux, how does the NVMe look in `lspci` and nvme-cli tools?

Comment: Please note this site allows only one question per post. Edit your question to focus on just one question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unbelievable. My motherboard give me the following table for PCIe usage:
[PCIe Slots Motherboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FunGV.png)

So I decided for the 4th Slot to be most far away from the graphic card and to have definitely min. 4 lanes. Now I changed to the 2th Slot with max. 4 lanes and I get my wish speed. 
[Benchmark NVME PM981a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daR6y.png)

Comment: Now please accept the answer.

Comment: This is not possible. I can use this function not until tomorrow.